# Splunk: Group by certain entry in log file

Tags: group-by, splunk, splunk-query

I did this query in Splunk:

```
source="/log/ABCD/cABCDXYZ/xyz.log" doSomeTasks|timechart partial=f span=1h count as "#XYZ doSomeTasks" |fillnull
```

This query works out fine. Now, I would like to group this results by another entry in my log file. This entry is `taskType`. `taskType` can be either `One`, `Two` or `Three`. `One`, `Two` or `Three` are also entries after `taskType`.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [`by` clause](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/timechart) to your `timechart`:

```
source="/log/ABCD/cABCDXYZ/xyz.log" doSomeTasks
| timechart partial=f span=1h count as "#XYZ doSomeTasks" by taskType
| fillnull
```

Comment: You are right! before that I had to extract a regular expression of the necessary fiel `taskType`. Then it worked as you described it in your answer.

Comment: @Tobitor - the field *definitely* does need to be present to use as a grouping field :)